# How do I use methods from an existing running thread in different Activities

Tags: java, android, multithreading, listener

I got the following problem. My App has 5 activities and works as TCP-Client. If I start the App, activity 1 gets started and establishes a connection with a server.

This activity owns a listener for getting incomming Data.

```
public void messageReceived(final String message) {
        RemoteActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
              RemoteActivity.this.GetMessage(message);                              
        }
        });
}
```

Now my question: Is there any possibility to use this thread in the other activities? How can I add more listeners from other activities to this thread?

Thanks for hints Guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply make your TCPWorker a singleton, and you'll be able to access it from different activities. Note, you need to shut off the thread after you are done with it, otherwise, it will run until android kills your app.

An example:

```
public class TCPWorker {

    //Your static worker object
    private static TCPWorker worker;
    private TCPListener listener;

    //The method that activities use to access your TCPWorker object
    public static TCPWorker worker() {
        if (worker == null) {
            worker = new TCPWorker();
        }
        return worker;
    }

    //Make your constructor private, activities should only access your worker from the singleton method.
    private TCPWorker() {
        //Initialize the worker
    }

    public void setTCPListener(TCPListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void getTCPListener() {
        return this.listener;
    }

}
```

Cheers